# Primary index in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have defined primary index on three columns as below

primary index ( col1,col2,col3)

To query the table using this index will the order of col1,col2,col3 in the predicate matter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as a PI in Teradata is a hashed index.